# How to fine-tune the number of cluster in k-means clustering and incremental way of building the model using BigQuery ML

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

Used K-means clustering Model for detecting anomaly using BigQuery ML.

Datasets information

```
date Date
trade_id INT
trade_name STRING
agent_id INT
agent_name String
total_item INT
```

Mapping - **One trade has multiple agent based on date.**
Model Trained with below information by `sum(total_iteam)`

```
trade_id 
trade_name
agent_id
agent_name
```

```
Number of cluster: 4
```

Need to find the anomaly for each trades and agent based on date.
Model is trained with given set of data and `distance_from_closest_centroid` is calculated. for each trade and agent based on date distance is called. Rightest distance is consider as a anomaly. Using this information

**Questions
1.** How to find the number of cluster need to use for model(eg: Elbow method used for selecting minimal cluster number selection).

**Questions
2.** How to build the model in case when trade data added on daily basis. Its is possible to build the incremental way of building the model on daily basis.

Comment: According to the documentation, if you omit `num_clusters` using K-means, BigQuery ML will choose a reasonable amount based in the number of rows in the training data. In addition, you can also use hyperparameter tuning to determine a optimal number of clusters. Thus, you would have to run the `CREATE MODEL` query for different values of `num_clusters`, find the error measure and pick the point which the error is minimum, [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/kmeans-tutorial).

Comment: Also, pay attention that [num_clusters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create) goes from 2 to 100. Were both information helpful for you?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Thanks for information. This really helpful.

Comment: would you mind if I sum up the information I shared as an answer ? So it would contribute more to the community.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes hi. I have question about building the model(incremental way of building model). I have edit my question kindly have look- Thanks

Comment: Question 1 is already answered. Question 2: K-means is an unsupervised machine learning algorithm, within Bigquery your ML model  will be stored in your data set. After trained, you can use the model with new data using [ML.PREDICT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/kmeans-tutorial#use_ml.predict). Did you understand it ?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes agree with your point. My question is I have one year of trade data. My data update on daily basis. I have trained my model with one year data. Let say i have daily data approaching my model so using predict model i will calculate the distance that fine . How will i train the model with upcoming data should i need to build the all the one year data(already build) or upcoming data(appending the data to model). Just clarification

Comment: K-means will utilise the previous data (of one year ago) to create the model. So, if you are continuously receiving data from the same end point, your data should follow the same behaviour as one year ago. Therefore, the model will work for the new data.  Is it clear for you? Also, consider upvoting and accepting the answer I posted summarising our discussion.

Comment: Yes @AlexandreMoraes My question is about building model. I have already build the model for one year data. Using this model i have analysed upcoming one or two month of data. Now I want to rebuild the model because new trade information has to be updated in my existing model. In this case is this possible to append the model with only two month of data or should we need to rebuild the entire model

Comment: You would have to retrain the whole model if new relevant data arrives. Although, I must mention that you can and should use `warm_start` to retrain your already existing model, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#warm_start). Please, do not forget to accept and upvote the answer I posted. I will be updating it with the new information from our discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question was updated, I will sum up our discussion as an answer to further contribute to the community.

1. *Regarding your first question* ***"How to find the number of cluster need to use for model(eg: Elbow method used for selecting minimal cluster number selection)."*.**

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/kmeans-tutorial#query_details_2), if you omit the `num_clusters` option, BigQuery ML will choose a reasonable default based on the total number of rows in the training data. However, if you want to select the most optimal number, you can perform hyperarameter tunning, which is the process of selecting one (or a set) of optimal hyperparameter for a learning algorithm, in your case K-means within BigQuery ML. In order to determine the ideal number of clusters you would run `CREATE MODEL` query for different values of `num_clusters`. Then , finding the error measure and select the point which it is at the minimum value. You can select the error measure in the training tab ***Evaluation***, it will show the ***Davies–Bouldin index*** and ***Mean squared distance***.

2. *Your second question was **"How to build the model in case when trade data added on daily basis. Its is possible to build the incremental way of building the model on daily basis."***

K-means is an unsupervised leaning algorithm. So you will train your model with your current data. Then store it in a data set. This model is already trained and can certainly be used with new data, using the [ML.PREDICT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/kmeans-tutorial#use_ml.predict). So it will use the model to predict which clusters the new data belong to.

*As a bonus information, I would like to share this [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-use-bigquery-ml-for-anomaly-detection) for the documentation which explains how K-means in BigQuery ML can be used to detect data anomaly.*

**UPDATE:**

Regarding your question about retraining the model:

**Question:** "I want to rebuild the model because new trade information has to be updated in my existing model. In this case is this possible to append the model with only two month of data or should we need to rebuild the entire model?"

**Answer:** You would have to retrain the whole model if new relevant data arrives. There is not the possibility to append the model with only two months of new data. Although, I must mention that you can and should use `warm_start` to retrain your already existing model, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#warm_start).

Answer (score 0):

As per @Alexandre Moraes 
omiting the num_clusters using K-means, BigQuery ML will choose a reasonable amount based in the number of rows in the training data. In addition, you can also use hyperparameter tuning to determine a optimal number of clusters. Thus, you would have to run the CREATE MODEL query for different values of num_clusters, find the error measure and pick the point which the error is minimum, [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/kmeans-tutorial). –